# Setup makefile to check both c and c++ source files with emacs flymake

Tags: c++, c, emacs, makefile, flymake

I am trying to set up syntax checking with flymake and I've got the basic setup working.

My makefile for flymake is simply like follows:

```
INCLUDES = -I ./inc ## list of more includes omitted for brevity
.PHONY: check-syntax
check-syntax:
    gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fsyntax-only -Wno-variadic-macros -std=c99 $(INCLUDES) $(CHK_SOURCES)
```

This works ok for my C sources.

Now how to use the same makefile and the same check-syntax target for C++? I can't set multiple -std options like -std=c99 -std=c++98 to the same gcc invocation or can I? Do I need to use some conditional? I can't have multiple check-syntax targets on the same Makefile.

Comment: You can make `check-syntax` depend on multiple other targets though:  `check-syntax: check-syntax-c check-syntax-cpp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split it up into two targets:

```
check-syntax: check-syntax-c check-syntax-cxx
```

Then check the syntax using the C compiler and the C flags in one target, and using the C++ and C++ flags for the other.

Although you have to split up your sources in C and C++ sources, which you should do anyway.

---

If you don't have the files split already, you can do it using a GNU Make [text function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) named `filter` to split the sources:

```
CHK_SOURCES_C   = $(filter %.c,$(CHK_SOURCES))
CHK_SOURCES_CXX = $(filter %.cpp,$(CHK_SOURCES))
```

Comment: Actually the C and C++ are already split into separate folders which have separate makefiles but I would not like to add flymake support to each and everyone of those. Instead I would like to direct the flymake to use just the top level makefile. CHK_SOURCES in that case contains whatever flymake is feeding into it. So it may contain a c or c++ source file name.

Comment: @teroi Updated the answer with how you can split into C and C++ source files.

Comment: Ah, now I see your point. I know the filter function; just don't didn't think this through... That is actually quite clean solution. i'll test drive this.

Comment: Ok, quite good already but it is trying to build both check-syntax-c and check-syntax-cpp targets even though either the CHK_SOURCES_C or CHK_SOURCE_CXX is empty...

Comment: @teroi Look at the [conditional functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html#Conditional-Functions). Define and use a specific target *if* the corresponding source-file macro is non-empty

Comment: I ended up using http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_7.html . So no conditional functions but just conditionals. I am accepting the answer since I got to the right direction by the help of that and the additional comments.

Comment: It must be also noted that flymake will generate a temporary copy of the file which it will compile. So any .c file will be copied to .c_flymake, for example. So when splitting the sources we'll need to filter CHK_SOURCES with %.c_flymake and %.cpp_flymake patterns.